# How insert a character at a specific position of a string pointer efficiently?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I try to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-palindrome. My solution failed as `Time Limit Exceeded`

```c
char *insert(char *s, char t, int pos){
    int i, n = strlen(s);
    s = (char *)realloc(s, n+2);
    for(i = n+1; i > pos; --i) s[i] = s[i-1];
    s[pos] = t;
    return s;
}


char *shortestPalindrome(char *s){
    int n = strlen(s);
    char p[n+1];
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) p[i] = s[n-i-1];
    p[n]= '\0';
    char *s1 = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
    char *s2 = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
    strcpy(s1, s);
    strcpy(s2, p);
    int l = 0;
    while(strcmp(s1, s2)!=0){
        s1 = insert(s1, s2[l], l);
        s2 = insert(s2, s2[l], strlen(s2)-l);
        ++l;
    }
    free(s1);
    return s2;
}
```

My implementation of `insert` has low efficiency, I hope for a wiser improvement, I'm stuck with it as I can't operate character behind `pos` as a whole.

---

```
char *insert(char *s, char t, int pos){
    int i, n = strlen(s);
    for(i = n+1; i > pos; --i) s[i] = s[i-1];
    s[pos] = t;
    return s;
}


char * shortestPalindrome(char *s){
    int n = strlen(s);
    char p[n+1];
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) p[i] = s[n-i-1];
    p[n]= '\0';
    char *s1 = malloc(2*n*sizeof(int));
    char *s2 = malloc(2*n*sizeof(int));
    char *p2 = p;
    strcpy(s1, s);
    strcpy(s2, p2);
    int l = 0;
    while(strcmp(s1, s2)!=0){
        s1 = insert(s1, s2[l], l);
        s2 = insert(s2, s2[l], strlen(s2)-l);
        ++l;
    }
    free(s1);
    return s2;
}
```

Even I allocate space only twice, it still failed  as `Time Limit Exceeded`

---

Taking advice from the comment area, I apply `memmove` this time.

```c
char * shortestPalindrome(char *s){
    int n = strlen(s);
    char p[n+1];
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) p[i] = s[n-i-1];
    p[n]= '\0';
    char *s1 = malloc(2*n*sizeof(char));
    char *s2 = malloc(2*n*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s1, s);
    strcpy(s2, p);
    printf("%s %s\n", s1, s2);
    int l = 0, l1, l2;
    while(strcmp(s1, s2)!=0){
        l1 = strlen(s1), l2 = strlen(s2);
        memmove(&s1[l + 1], &s1[l], l1 - l);
        memmove(&s1[l], &s2[l], 1);
        memmove(&s2[l2 - l + 1],  &s2[l2 - l], l);
        memmove(&s2[l2 - l],  &s2[l], 1);
        printf("%s %s\n", s1, s2);
        ++l;
    }
    free(s1);
    return s2;
}
```

yet there is a bug still, It falls into an infinite loop, the weird thing is that I debug it with `lldb` step by step it would exit normally.

---

Bug found! For some reason, string terminator is missing.

```c
char * shortestPalindrome(char *s){
    int n = strlen(s);
    char p[n+1];
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) p[i] = s[n-i-1];
    p[n]= '\0';
    char *s1 = malloc(2*n*sizeof(char));
    char *s2 = malloc(2*n*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s1, s);
    strcpy(s2, p);
    printf("%s %s\n", s1, s2);
    int l = 0, l1, l2;
    while(strcmp(s1, s2)!=0 && l < n){
        l1 = strlen(s1), l2 = strlen(s2);
        memmove(&s1[l + 1], &s1[l], l1 - l);
        memmove(&s1[l], &s2[l], 1);
        memmove(&s1[l1+1], &"\0", 1);
        memmove(&s2[l2 - l + 1],  &s2[l2 - l], l);
        memmove(&s2[l2 - l],  &s2[l], 1);
        memmove(&s2[l2 + 1],  &"\0", 1);
        printf("%s %s\n", s1, s2);
        ++l;
    }
    free(s1);
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: `malloc()` and `realloc()` are relatively expensive operations. Instead of allocating or reallocating for every character, why not allocate blocks of 100 or 256 (whatever) and keep track of the length and only reallocate when you reach your limit. `memmove()` will be much more efficient than a loop moving each character above the inserted character.

Comment: Don't call `realloc` inside the function. From start you know an upper limit for the result string so simply allocate that memory from the start.

Comment: @4386427 for the consideration of saving space, the upperlimit is `2*sizeof(s)-1` yet in the worst case it might only need  space very close to `sizeof(s)`

Comment: Then simply allocate that amount in the first `malloc`. Also use `memmove` instead of your own loop

Comment: `sizeof(int)` hmm... `sizeof(char)` ?

Comment: Don't call `strlen` again and again

Comment: @4386427 I do not understand that how `memmove` can replace my own loop, `void *memmove(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)` is for copying the first n characters of `str2` to `str1`,  I need a operation which can be  expressed`s[:pos] + t + s[pos:]` in python

Comment: hmm... you only want to insert in the front, i.e. `t + s[pos:]`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Even 4k. Most systems will allocate 4k anyway